# Applying multiple if-else conditions on different columns in R

Tags: r, if-statement, nested

[image][image]I have the following dataset:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3
      3         3         1        
      2         3         2        
      1        NA         2        
     NA         4         1        
      2        NA        NA        
     NA        NA        NA
```

I want to create a new column (Column 4) with the following conditions:

1. If columns 1 and 2 have the same value, the value in column 4 is the same as columns 1 and 2.
2. If columns 1 and 2 have different values, the value in column 4 should be 5.
3. If column 1 or column 2 have an NA, pick the value from column 3.
4. If 2 columns out of 3 have NA, then the value in column 4 should be that of the column that has a non-NA value.
5. If all the columns have NA, then column 4 should have NA too.

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4
      3         3         1         3 (Condition 1) 
      2         3         2         5 (Condition 2)
      1        NA         2         2 (Condition 3)
     NA         4         1         1 (Condition 3)
      2        NA        NA         2 (Condition 4)
     NA        NA        NA        NA (Condition 5)
```

Thanks in advance for answering this query.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
df <- read.table(text = "Column1   Column2   Column3
      3         3         1        
      2         3         2        
      1        NA         2        
     NA         4         1        
      2        NA        NA        
     NA        NA        NA   ", header = T)


df %>%
  mutate(col4 = case_when(
    is.na(Column1) & is.na(Column2) & is.na(Column3) ~ NA_real_, # Con 5
    is.na(Column1) | is.na(Column2) & !is.na(Column3) ~ as.numeric(Column3), #Con 3
    !is.na(Column1) & is.na(Column2) |is.na(Column3) ~ as.numeric(Column1), #Con4
    Column1 == Column2  ~ as.numeric(Column1), #Con 1
    TRUE ~ 5 #Con 2
  ))

  Column1 Column2 Column3  col4
    <int>   <int>   <int> <dbl>
1       3       3       1     3
2       2       3       2     5
3       1      NA       2     2
4      NA       4       1     1
5       2      NA      NA     2
6      NA      NA      NA    NA
```

## New code

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  ck6ethrace = c(2,2,3,2,2,2,NA,NA,2,NA,3,NA,1,3,NA,2,NA,2,4,2),
  cm1ethrace = c(2,2,3,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,2,1,3,1,2,3,2,4,2),
  cf1ethrace = c(2,2,3,2,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,2,1,3,3,2,3,2,4,2)
)
dummy %>%
  mutate(race = case_when(
    is.na(ck6ethrace) & is.na(cm1ethrace) & is.na(cf1ethrace) ~ NA_real_, # Con 5
    is.na(ck6ethrace) | is.na(cm1ethrace) & !is.na(cf1ethrace) ~ as.numeric(cf1ethrace), #Con 3
    !is.na(ck6ethrace) & is.na(cm1ethrace) |is.na(cf1ethrace) ~ as.numeric(ck6ethrace), #Con4
    ck6ethrace == cm1ethrace  ~ as.numeric(ck6ethrace), #Con 1
    TRUE ~ 5 #Con 2
  ))
```

result

```
   ck6ethrace cm1ethrace cf1ethrace race
1           2          2          2    2
2           2          2          2    2
3           3          3          3    3
4           2          1          2    5
5           2          2          2    2
6           2          2          2    2
7          NA          2          3    3
8          NA          1          1    1
9           2          2          2    2
10         NA          2          2    2
11          3          3          2    3
12         NA          2          2    2
13          1          1          1    1
14          3          3          3    3
15         NA          1          3    3
16          2          2          2    2
17         NA          3          3    3
18          2          2          2    2
19          4          4          4    4
20          2          2          2    2
```

Comment: I tried this but the new column is not getting added. Also, column 1,2 and 3 are of the type: "dbl+lbl".

Comment: @TannyaKumar I read `df` with the code I add above. Would you mind to tell me if it doesn't work with that `df`?

Comment: @TannyaKumar are you assigning the result? `df <- df %>% ...`?

Comment: So, column 1 in my dataset is the mother's race, column 2 is the father's race and column 3 is the child's self-reported race. There are a total of 4898 values (including NAs). I want to create column 4 (and name it 'race') such that the column contains values with the above specified conditions.

Comment: @TannyaKumar if the column names are giving you trouble, I'd suggest updating the column names in your question to match what you say in your comment.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for notice that. I tried another way before and I need that `rowwise`. I forgot to remove that. Thanks again.:D

Comment: @TannyaKumar If you are able to provide some result of `dput(head(yourdata, 20))`, then I think that I can add a code for your data. Or you may change column's name as @Gregor Thomas said.

Comment: Hi, I added images. These are the first 20. However, there are 4,898 entries in my dataset.

Comment: @TannyaKumar I didn't expect image but try to take a look at my code. I add some above.

Comment: Thanks for the new code but the original dataset has 4,898 values and not 20 values. This means I cannot manually create a dataset as you have done above. In the image, I am displaying only the first 20 values. So in my df, I cannot manually add 4,898 values.

Comment: @TannyaKumar It doesn't matter with size of dataframe. Just change `dummy` to `your data name` will work.

Comment: So, my question is that if I change dummy to my data name, and feed only the top 20 values in it, then the change will reflect only in the top 20 variables, right?

Comment: @TannyaKumar Yes, that's right.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your response.